# Automatic multiplication for several row

Tags: javascript

I'm new on coding, then any help will greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to make automatic multiplication from 2 value. Basically my table looks like [this](http://jsbin.com/wimuxejuki/edit?html,js,output). Multiplication works perfectly on the first row. If I make another row by simply copying this code:

```
<tr>
   <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
   <td><input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
   <td><input id="result" /></td>
</tr>
```

then the second row won't work. This may happen because the `id` on second row exactly same with the first row. But if I change the `id`, the script won't work either. Would you please show me how to fix it?

EDIT: I use this scrip for multiplication purpose:

```
function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    result.value = myResult;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your Javascript - at least the `calculate` method.

Comment: @UncleDave I've edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would bind a single `input` event handler to the table, which will catch any `input` events on any of the table cells' input elements. Within the handler `event.target` will refer to the input element where the event originated, and you can use DOM navigation properties/methods to find the associated table cells in the same row.

Maybe a little something like this, using `class` instead of `id`:

```js
document.getElementById("multiplier").addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode
  var val1 = row.querySelector(".valOne").value
  var val2 = row.querySelector(".valTwo").value
  row.querySelector(".result").value = val1 * val2
})
```

```html
<table id="multiplier">
<tr>
   <td><input class="valOne" type="text" /></td>
   <td><input class="valTwo" type="text" /></td>
   <td><input class="result" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input class="valOne" type="text" /></td>
   <td><input class="valTwo" type="text" /></td>
   <td><input class="result" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input class="valOne" type="text" /></td>
   <td><input class="valTwo" type="text" /></td>
   <td><input class="result" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Further reading:

- [`.addEventListener()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`.parentNode` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)
- [`.querySelector()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

It would be better to use `e.target.closest("tr")` instead of `e.target.parentNode.parentNode`, but note that the [`.closest()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) isn't supported in IE so you would need to use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill).

Note that the JS that I've shown would need to be in a script element that is *after* the table (e.g., at the end of the body right before the closing `</body>` tag), or you'd need to wrap it in a document load or DOMContentLoaded handler.